# How can I make some command to run at certain times after login?

Tags: 12.10, startup

I want to run some executable files, not when system startup, but after a few second after login?

It is a *.sh files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a master bash file that contain a sleep time & all your executable.

Like,

```
#!/bin/bash          
sleep 30 && StartmyJob1.sh
```

Now make this `master.sh` file to run at startup.

Also refer to this guide [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: Will *.sh be executed after 30 seconds? Where do I put my *.sh files?

Comment: yes.. you can keep sh file anywhere. Just add a entry in `start up`  application. Follow this guide [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48321). For a system wide get knowledge of `upstart`